# Examples of math problems which exhibited deceptive progress

Tags: mathematics, mathematics-social-history

I'm interested in gathering a list of problems in the history of maths where people were committed to a particular strategy for some time, only to find out that the approach was fundamentally flawed.

I expect all famous and unsolved problems in mathematics probably have something resembling this quality. I'm not too sure of its history, but I would imagine there are a lot of naive (and not so naive) attempts at the Goldbach conjecture that many put a lot of faith in.

Something like the natural proofs barrier for P vs. NP is probably the best exemplar I can think of.

If possible, I would like to gather examples that were solved and which didn't prove a negative result (i.e., Fermat's Last Theorem)

Comment: What about attempts to prove the parallel postulate in
Euclidean geometry?

Comment: [Stallings, How not to prove the Poincaré conjecture](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.3404) is a classic. His approach was typical of various homotopic constructions that topologists favored. In the end, it was proved using PDE, Hamilton's strategy from 1970s that few other than him and Perelman pursued. It inspired imitations, e.g. [How not to prove the Alon-Tarsi conjecture](https://users.monash.edu.au/~iwanless/papers/AlonTarsiNMJ.pdf). See also a [list of misguided proofs on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/879).

Comment: Bertrand Russell's *Principia Mathematica* comes to mind. Huge task, but Gödel came with his incompleteness theorem that undermines it.

Comment: An example that doesn't seem to be included in the others is [**Dirichlet's Principle. A Mathematical Comedy of Errors and its Influence on the Development of Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9031301752) by Antonie [Anton] Frans Monna (1975). [A copy](https://archive.org/details/dirichletsprinci0000monn) can be borrowed at the internet archive. [Reviewed by Grattan-Guinness](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82364968.pdf), where interestingly I notice that Grattan-Guinness points out (first full paragraph on p. 224) **(continued)**

Comment: something I've also found in a lot of Monna's work (I mentioned it at the end of [this 5 March 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/ARoOE92Ozeo/m/V7bHPSWFO5kJ)), namely that Monna tends to include a large number of (sometimes lengthy) quotes in the original German, French, Italian, etc. in an English paper without providing a translation.

Comment: The story of the solution of the Four-Colour Problem is a worthy contender.